# Error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’ and ‘std::complex<double>’)

Tags: c++, vector, complex-numbers

I use the vector class with complex numbers and I have to multiply a vector of complex numbers with a complex number, like this:

```
vector< complex<double> > vec;
complex<double> z;
// some initialization of vec and z ...
vector< complex<double> > res;
res = vec*z;   // here is the error
```

`error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’ and ‘std::complex<double>’)`

Is it possible to overload operator* with these parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Here is how you can implement your own operator `*` for `complex<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
vector<complex<T>> operator *(const vector<complex<T>>& v, const complex<T> z) {
    vector<complex<T>> res;
    transform(v.begin(), v.end(), back_inserter(res), 
        [&](complex<T> x) -> complex<T> {
            return x * z;
        });
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I've edited to remove the scroll bar. Interesting question whether this is easier to read than a properly formatted version of `vector<complex<T>> res(v); for (auto& x: res) x*=z; return res;` , and what the relative performance characteristics are.